# How can I startup react app on live server (cpanel)

Tags: reactjs

react beginner question...

I am learning react on my Mac and I installed NPM and node js and created a basic react app for testing.

In VS code app - when I type in terminal 'npm start' it opens a browser and shows the app running. - all good

Next I tried to upload the app to a live Web server (it has cpanel).

Seems like it is not connected to react - or somehow I need to start the app?

What can I do to start / connect it?

the URL is something like:

```
https://example.com/reactlearn/
or
https://example.com/reactlearn/public/
empty
or
https://example.com/reactlearn/src/

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deploying it to Vercel, Netlify or Heroku.

These should all provide free options with a url where you can see the app.